# How to disable UI sounds (button press)

Tags: 18.04, sound

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 and there´s some weird behavior with certain UI events and sounds.

Some system dialogs will sound a little blip when clicking a button. 
This is **not** one of the alert sounds as found in the **Sound > Sound effects** tab on the system settings (ie. *Default*, *Bark*, *Drip*, *Glass*, *Sonar*).

Another, similar, blip type sound is played when I make a selection or clear a selection when using Inkscape.

Over time I've tried many times to find and find the settings for this, to no avail.

I'd really like to be able to disable this sound as it's super annoying. 
Again, this is not the Alert sound, but something else.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try the command:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/sound/event-sounds false
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.sound input-feedback-sounds false
```

I hope I understood it right. It is sound, when you press keys on your keyboard.